# Combinations of shift-invariant sets

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A=\{a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{\ell-1}\}$ be a finite set.
Let $A^m$ be the set of  the $\ell^m$ sequences of elements of $A$ having length $m$.
The set $A^m$ can be partitioned in a number of shift-invariant subsets, defined in the following way.
Let $X = (x_0, x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_{m-1}), \;x_i \in A$ be an element of $A^m$.
The shift-invariant subset $<X>$ is defined as

$<X> = \{(x_0, x_1,\dots,x_{m-1}), (x_1, x_2,\dots,x_{m-2},x_0), \dots,
(x_{m-1},x_0,x_1,\dots, x_{m-2})\}$

The set $\mathcal{P}$ of all the shift-invariant sets form a partition of $A^m$.
How many shift-invariant sets are there?
Note that there are up to $m$ (distinct) elements in a shift-invariant set. Thus, the number of
$n$ of shift-invariant sets is bounded by
$$\ell^{m}/m \leq n \leq \ell^m.$$

Furthermore, if m is prime, 
$$ n = (\ell^m-\ell)/m+\ell$$
since all the shift-invariant sets contain $m$ distinct elements, except the $\ell$ shift-invariant sets in the form 
$<\bar X_i> = \{(a_i,a_i,\dots,a_i)\},\;i=0,1,\dots,\ell$
which contain only one sequence of constant values.